# ES6 - Javascript - Jquery external not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, babeljs, yarnpkg

I have some files
app.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
// export for others scripts to use
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
import personnal from './assets/js/personnal';
import {cube,machin} from './assets/js/exporting';


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div#testok").css({"border":"5px solid black"});

});
```

In the app.js file jquery working but in my custom file "personnal.js" jquery is undefined

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log($('div#testok'));

});
console.log('loading personnal');
```

I use yarn,

```
{
  "name": "yarnes6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify",
        {
          "presets": [
            "es2015"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify app.js -o dist/bundle.js",
    "watch": "watchify app.js -o dist/bundle.js -v"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^16.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "reading-time": "^1.2.0",
    "watchify": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^8"
  }
}
```

It's not possible to use jquery directly on my personnal file? what is the method?

Comment: Your script `personnal.js` might run before the `app.js` file

Comment: before app.js jquery not loading.There must be a possibility to add the whole code in app.js using importation

Comment: This ok for me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39820703/7851271 problem build with es6 et commonJS this solve