# Importing a locale for "bootstrap-datepicker"

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I import a locale package for [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library?

I'm trying with

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.js';
```

but in the browser console I get error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.js
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358625/jquery-is-not-defined-when-use-es6-import

Comment: @FredK did you solve your problem ? I'm facing the same issue here ...